# Unlist an object in R but replace numeric(0) with NAs

Tags: r, list, numeric

I currently have a dataframe with each column with dimnames. For the most part this isn't an issue, but I recently added to it a new column, `qgf`, that was read in as a list instead of a vector for some reason.

This is an example of what a few rows look like:

```
> wc_results_data[12:20, 23]
$wc_1930_Uruguay
numeric(0)

$wc_1930_USA
numeric(0)

$wc_1934_Argentina
numeric(0)

$wc_1934_Austria
[1] 6

$wc_1934_Belgium
[1] 6

$wc_1934_Brazil
numeric(0)

$`wc_1934_Czech Republic/CSFR`
[1] 2

$wc_1934_Egypt
[1] 11

$wc_1934_France
[1] 6
```

So as you can see, `wc_results_data[c(12:14, 17, 23]` are currently coded as `numeric(0)` when really they should be `NAs` (I should clarify that there are actual *values* of 0 in my code as well).

What's **really** bizarre about these values is that if I try and test them as such, I get weird results:

```
> wc_results_data[12,23]
$wc_1930_Uruguay
numeric(0)
> identical(wc_results_data[12,23], numeric(0))
[1] FALSE
> length(wc_results_data[12,23])
[1] 1
```

To try and solve this issue, I attempted to save this column using `unlist` as such:

wc_results_data[,23] <- unlist(wc_results_data[,23])

but I get this error:

`replacement has 368 rows, data has 425`

which makes sense of course, basically I have 57 observations that are `numeric(0)` but I CANNOT get rid of them. Is there a way to `unlist` and store these `numeric(0)` observations as `NA`s? Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Per a comment below, here is my output for `dput` on a few rows and columns of the data.frame:

```
dput( wc_results_data[12:20, 22:24])
structure(list(fgd = structure(c(12, 1, -1, 0, -3, -2, 3, -2, 
-1), .Dim = 9L, .Dimnames = list(c("wc_1930_Uruguay", "wc_1930_USA", 
"wc_1934_Argentina", "wc_1934_Austria", "wc_1934_Belgium", "wc_1934_Brazil", 
"wc_1934_Czech Republic/CSFR", "wc_1934_Egypt", "wc_1934_France"
))), qgf = structure(list(wc_1930_Uruguay = numeric(0), wc_1930_USA = numeric(0), 
    wc_1934_Argentina = numeric(0), wc_1934_Austria = 6, wc_1934_Belgium = 6, 
    wc_1934_Brazil = numeric(0), `wc_1934_Czech Republic/CSFR` = 2, 
    wc_1934_Egypt = 11, wc_1934_France = 6), .Dim = 9L, .Dimnames = list(
    c("wc_1930_Uruguay", "wc_1930_USA", "wc_1934_Argentina", 
    "wc_1934_Austria", "wc_1934_Belgium", "wc_1934_Brazil", "wc_1934_Czech Republic/CSFR", 
    "wc_1934_Egypt", "wc_1934_France"))), qga = structure(list(
    wc_1930_Uruguay = numeric(0), wc_1930_USA = numeric(0), wc_1934_Argentina = numeric(0), 
    wc_1934_Austria = 1, wc_1934_Belgium = 8, wc_1934_Brazil = numeric(0), 
    `wc_1934_Czech Republic/CSFR` = 1, wc_1934_Egypt = 2, wc_1934_France = 1), .Dim = 9L, .Dimnames = list(
    c("wc_1930_Uruguay", "wc_1930_USA", "wc_1934_Argentina", 
    "wc_1934_Austria", "wc_1934_Belgium", "wc_1934_Brazil", "wc_1934_Czech Republic/CSFR", 
    "wc_1934_Egypt", "wc_1934_France")))), .Names = c("fgd", 
"qgf", "qga"), row.names = 12:20, class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: `numeric(0)` is not the number `0` but is rather a numeric vector of length-0. Since they are of length 0 you could test for that feature. That a really bizarre output for `wc_results_data[12:20, 23]` under the assumption that `wc_results_data` is a dataframe. Rows of dataframes don't typically appear as list members. Writing code to address this would be better supported if you would post the output of `dput( wc_results_data[12:20, 22:24])`

Comment: Yeah it's really bizarre. I just added the output for `dput` into the main post

Comment: Could you also include your expected output. It's not clear to me what you want to do. In your sample data, columns `qgf` and `qga` contain `list`s. Do you simply want to remove zero-length entries but keep the `list`s, or is this about  unnesting entries in the list?

Comment: @MauritsEvers I would like to unnest the entries in the list so that I can "recode" these `numeric(0)` values as NAs

Comment: Thanks for the clarification; I've added a potential solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assigned the `dput` output to the name `wc_results_data` and here is the print output:

```
wc_results_data
   fgd qgf qga
12  12        
13   1        
14  -1        
15   0   6   1
16  -3   6   8
17  -2        
18   3   2   1
19  -2  11   2
20  -1   6   1
```

The results of `str` on the column in question is:

```
str(wc_results_data$qgf)
List of 9
 $ wc_1930_Uruguay            : num(0) 
 $ wc_1930_USA                : num(0) 
 $ wc_1934_Argentina          : num(0) 
 $ wc_1934_Austria            : num 6
 $ wc_1934_Belgium            : num 6
 $ wc_1934_Brazil             : num(0) 
 $ wc_1934_Czech Republic/CSFR: num 2
 $ wc_1934_Egypt              : num 11
 $ wc_1934_France             : num 6
 - attr(*, "dim")= int 9
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 1
  ..$ : chr [1:9] "wc_1930_Uruguay" "wc_1930_USA" "wc_1934_Argentina" "wc_1934_Austria" ...
```

I needed to use `sapply` on that column to "apply" the `length` function:

```
is.na( wc_results_data$qgf) <- sapply( wc_results_data$qgf, length) == 0
> wc_results_data
   fgd qgf qga
12  12  NA    
13   1  NA    
14  -1  NA    
15   0   6   1
16  -3   6   8
17  -2  NA    
18   3   2   1
19  -2  11   2
20  -1   6   1
```

You may need to loop over all columns with this method first, so that you can then modify it so that it behaves like a regular dataframe. Just using `unlist` on those columns fails to make a dataframe-able result.

Answer (score 3):

Provided I understood correctly, here is a `dplyr` solution:

```
library(tidyverse);
df %>%
    mutate(
        qgf = unlist(ifelse(sapply(qgf, length) == 0, NA, qgf)),
        qga = unlist(ifelse(sapply(qga, length) == 0, NA, qga)))
#  fgd qgf qga
#1  12  NA  NA
#2   1  NA  NA
#3  -1  NA  NA
#4   0   6   1
#5  -3   6   8
#6  -2  NA  NA
#7   3   2   1
#8  -2  11   2
#9  -1   6   1
```

Actually the only `dplyr` dependence is `mutate` so a base R solution is just as simple:

```
df$qgf <- unlist(ifelse(sapply(df$qgf, length) == 0, NA, df$qgf));
df$qga <- unlist(ifelse(sapply(df$qga, length) == 0, NA, df$qga));
```

---

### Sample data

```
df <- structure(list(fgd = structure(c(12, 1, -1, 0, -3, -2, 3, -2,
-1), .Dim = 9L, .Dimnames = list(c("wc_1930_Uruguay", "wc_1930_USA",
"wc_1934_Argentina", "wc_1934_Austria", "wc_1934_Belgium", "wc_1934_Brazil",
"wc_1934_Czech Republic/CSFR", "wc_1934_Egypt", "wc_1934_France"
))), qgf = structure(list(wc_1930_Uruguay = numeric(0), wc_1930_USA = numeric(0),
    wc_1934_Argentina = numeric(0), wc_1934_Austria = 6, wc_1934_Belgium = 6,
    wc_1934_Brazil = numeric(0), `wc_1934_Czech Republic/CSFR` = 2,
    wc_1934_Egypt = 11, wc_1934_France = 6), .Dim = 9L, .Dimnames = list(
    c("wc_1930_Uruguay", "wc_1930_USA", "wc_1934_Argentina",
    "wc_1934_Austria", "wc_1934_Belgium", "wc_1934_Brazil", "wc_1934_Czech Republic/CSFR",
    "wc_1934_Egypt", "wc_1934_France"))), qga = structure(list(
    wc_1930_Uruguay = numeric(0), wc_1930_USA = numeric(0), wc_1934_Argentina = numeric(0),
    wc_1934_Austria = 1, wc_1934_Belgium = 8, wc_1934_Brazil = numeric(0),
    `wc_1934_Czech Republic/CSFR` = 1, wc_1934_Egypt = 2, wc_1934_France = 1), .Dim = 9L, .Dimnames = list(
    c("wc_1930_Uruguay", "wc_1930_USA", "wc_1934_Argentina",
    "wc_1934_Austria", "wc_1934_Belgium", "wc_1934_Brazil", "wc_1934_Czech Republic/CSFR",
    "wc_1934_Egypt", "wc_1934_France")))), .Names = c("fgd",
"qgf", "qga"), row.names = 12:20, class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is one option with `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
   mutate_at(2:3, funs(map(., ~ .x[1]) ))
#  fgd qgf qga
#1  12  NA  NA
#2   1  NA  NA
#3  -1  NA  NA
#4   0   6   1
#5  -3   6   8
#6  -2  NA  NA
#7   3   2   1
#8  -2  11   2
#9  -1   6   1
```

The above keeps the column as a `list`, but if need to have it as a regular column, use `map_dbl`

```
df %>%
    mutate_at(2:3, funs(map_dbl(., ~ .x[1]) ))
```